# Upload stripeCharge function to Firebase cloud function not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I tried deploying this function to Firebase

Also, Im using Cloud Firestore as the database

```
const stripe = require("stripe")("STRIPE_API_KEY");
exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
  .document("/payments/{userId}/{paymentId}")
  .onWrite(event => {
    const payment = event.data.val();
    const userId = event.params.userId;
    const paymentId = event.params.paymentId;

    // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
    if (!payment || payment.charge) return;

    return admin
      .firestore()
      .doc(`/users/${userId}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.val();
      })
      .then(customer => {
        const amount = payment.amount;
        const idempotency_key = paymentId; // prevent duplicate charges
        const source = payment.token.id;
        const currency = "eur";
        const charge = { amount, currency, source };

        return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key });
      })

      .then(charge => {
        admin
          .firestore()
          .doc(`/payments/${userId}/${paymentId}/charge`)
          .set(charge),
          { merge: true };
      });
  });
```

I followed this tutorial

[Process Stripe Payments with Firebase Cloud Functions - Part 2
YouTube · 14 000+ views · 2017/07/11 · by Fireship - AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-stripe-payments-part-2-firebase-cloud-functions-backend/)

When I run `firebase deploy --only functions`

This appears in the terminal

```
!  functions: failed to create function stripeCharge
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        stripeCharge


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:stripeCharge


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

And I get this error in the Firebase log
[Firebase Log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki82t.png)

Anybody have a clue with what could be wrong?

Comment: Which version of Cloud Functions for Firebase are you using. It seems you use an old syntax, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore. You should check in your `package.json` file and confirm that this syntax is in line with your version. Can you add the content of this `package.json` file to your question. In any case it would be a good idea to migrate to a recent CF version.

Comment: `{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "stripe": "^6.25.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
`

Comment: Thanks for the link to that docs, you're right, I've been using the old syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one of your problem is that you use the syntax of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions for version **<** 1.0.0 and your `package.json` shows that you use a  version that is >= 2.2.0.

You should use the new syntax:

```
exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
  .document("/payments/{userId}/{paymentId}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

    const payment = change.after.data();
    const userId = event.params.userId;
    const paymentId = event.params.paymentId;
    ...
});
```

Comment: @D.Hodges What do you mean?